# select (or click) specific radiobutton using jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I am trying to make specific radiobutton checked on page load and tried a lot of ways, but no one worked for me. This is a part of orderform on my webstore.

```
  <input type="radio" name="sPaymentCarrier" id="pC_2-1" value="1;2;0.00" 
onclick="countCarrierPrice( this )" />
<label for="pC_2-1">0</label>
```

Actually this radiobutton is the only on radiobutton on page, and it must be checked to let user make order.

I tried

```
$(function() {
    var $radios = $('input:radio[name=sPaymentCarrier]');
    if($radios.is(':checked') === false) {
        $radios.filter('[value=1;2;0.00]').attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

and

```
$('input:radio[name="sPaymentCarrier"]').filter('[value="1;2;0.00"]').attr('checked', true);
```

but none of these ways worked. Also I tried a lot of other codes, but when I refreshed page I still saw this button unchecked.
I guess maybe I have to set up jquery click on this button instead of select, but actually I cannot make this work.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If it is the only rb on the page, then it is more standard to use a checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

Since I see you also have some javascript for onclick just do the following:

```
$('#pC_2-1').click();
```

This assumes you want to also run the onclick handler you defined on your element.  If that is not the case setting the `attr` mentioned in the other answers will work just as fine.

*Side note*, if you only have one radio button on the page, maybe a checkbox would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
$("#pC_2-1").attr("checked", "checked");
```

You can adapt the selector as you wish, but the `checked` attribute needs to be set to `"checked"`, not `true`.

Comment: I've just tried this one - it doesn't work also. Maybe I should click it using jQuery? I have no idea why these ways does not work, maybe because of my shopscript (Quick.Cart) conflicts with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set `checked="checked"` on the element?

Answer (score 0):

Use the val() function to set checkboxes or radiobuttons values to true.